# expect middleware functin to call next function or send a http 400 code

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, jestjs

I would like to get into unit testing and want to test my Node API. I use Express with Typescript, for tests I use Jest. Before calling the controller middleware I call the route input validation middleware to check if the params and body variables are valid. Otherwise I will send a 400 error code.

```
this.router.route('/')
    .post(userValidations.validateCreateUser, userController.createUser);
```

This validation creates a schema to validate

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import joi, { SchemaLike } from '@hapi/joi';

import { validateRequest } from '../validator';

export function validateCreateUser (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const validationSchema: SchemaLike = joi.object().keys({
        body: joi.object().keys({
            username: joi.string().required(),
            password: joi.string().required(),
        }).unknown(true)
    }).unknown(true);

    validateRequest(validationSchema, request, response, next);
}
```

and calls the `valdateRequest` method. This method validates the `request` object against the `validationSchema` and calls the next function if the request input is valid. Otherwise it will respond with a 400 error code and send back the error details.

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import joi, { SchemaLike, ValidationResult, ValidationError } from '@hapi/joi';

export function validateRequest(validationSchema: SchemaLike, request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const validationResult: ValidationResult<Request> = joi.validate(request, validationSchema, {
        abortEarly: false
    });

    const validationError: ValidationError = validationResult.error;

    if (validationError) {
        response.status(400).json({
            message: 'The route validation failed.',
            details: validationError.details,
        });
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```

I would like to test the `validateRequest` function first. I want to pass in a predefined `request` object and a `validationSchema` and want to check if the next function gets called or the error response on invalid inputs.

Is it even possible to assume something? I have to create an Express `request` and `response` object. Further I have to check if the `nextFunction` was called. I started with this code

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import joi, { SchemaLike } from '@hapi/joi';

import { validateRequest } from '../../../src/interfaceAdapters/routeInputValidation/validator';

describe('The route input validator', () => {
    let nextFunction: NextFunction;
    let response: Response;

    beforeEach(() => {
        nextFunction = ():void => {
            console.log('Next function was called successfully.');
        }

        response = new Response();
    });

    it('calls the next middleware on a valid request', () => {
        const request: Request = new Request();
        request.params = {
            id: 'C56A4180-65AA-42EC-A945-5FD21DEC0538'
        };
        request.body = {};

        const validationSchema: SchemaLike = joi.object().keys({
            params: joi.object().keys({
                id: joi.string().guid().required(),
            }).unknown(true)
        }).unknown(true);

        // expect calling next function
        // validateRequest(validationSchema, request, response, nextFunction);
    });

    it('sends a HTTP 400 error on a invalid request', () => {
        const request: Request = new Request();
        request.params = {
            id: '12345'
        };
        request.body = {};

        const validationSchema: SchemaLike = joi.object().keys({
            params: joi.object().keys({
                id: joi.string().guid().required(),
            }).unknown(true)
        }).unknown(true);

        // expect calling res.status(400).json({})
        // validateRequest(validationSchema, request, response, nextFunction);
    });
});
```

I'm struggling with 3 problems.

- How to create an instance of `Request`
- How to create an instance of `Response`
- What do I have to expect? `expect(validateRequest(validationSchema, request, response, next)).to...`

It would be awesome if someone could explain how to test this properly. Maybe I have to restructure my business code but I tried to write it testable...

Comment: Why dont you make an actual API call (API level testing) from your Jest Unit Test case file instead of manually making `Request` object? Let me know if something like that works for you. Will post a solution.

Comment: well sure, this would work but I think this would not test a single unit, right =? Because the API call would only test the route, validator, controller, ... etc. in one call I think

Comment: Yes. It would test complete API. Will it work for you?

Comment: yes, this would work for me but I want to test the single function first. I don't want to test the whole thing, I would like to test each part on its own.

Comment: Will look into it and try to update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following code is API level unit test case logic.

```
import * as request from "supertest";
import * as app from "../src/app"; // Main file
import "reflect-metadata";

const faker = require("faker/locale/en_IND");

describe('The route input validator', () => {
    it('Calls the API - POST /api/foo', () => {

        const first_name = faker.name.firstName();
        const last_name = faker.name.lastName();
        const email = faker.internet.email();

        request(app).post("/api/foo")
            .set("accept", "application/json")
            .set("content-type", "application/json")
            .send({
                "firstName": firstName,
                "email": email,
                "mobile_no": mobileNo
            }).end(function (err, res) {
                // Something like this - Assertion
                expect(res.body.success).toBe(true);
            }).expect(200);
    });
});
```

Above code is something similar I have used for complete API level testing with proper assertions. Should be able to get you started.

Comment: thanks. I commented on the question comment section